# How to find the homogeneous equation of non-homogeneous equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have homework and I don't understand the request.

this is the task: (I'm translating from Hebrew, so I'm sorry for unclear details, if there are):

> Solve the following linear equations , and write down the solution of the appropriate homogeneous  equation.

[image]

What does he mean, "to write down the solution of the appropriate homogeneous  equation"?

What is the appropriate homogeneous equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case your system is of the form $A\bar{x}=\bar{b}$, where the matrix $A$ is
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
and $\bar{x}=(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})$, $\bar{b}=(1,1,1)$. The appropriate homogeneous equation is simply $A\bar{x}=\bar{0}$, where $\bar{0}=(0,0,0)$. So in practise, you just replace the constants on the right hand sides of your linear system to equal zeros in order to obtain the homogeneous equation.

Comment: I'd better ask before submit.  thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I think he wanted to solve the system which has $0$ instead of $1$ on LHS. Therefore, it is clear that $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$ is its trivial solution